# jQuery offset, position element under another, where the right borders touch of the aligned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Ok, the subject is not super specific to the overall need I am looking to address. So I have this function that is called on a given element, which is a hidden submenu next to a triggering element. The way the page renders, and to keep the styling optimized I can't just style the position in via css. So I need javascript/jquerys help.

With that I have come up with a function that I can reuse as needed, and works fine all around. However my key problem is, that I have a couple cases where the submenu will overlap the edge of the `<section>` element it resides in. Which that elements overflow is set to hidden, that and its also about 30 pixels from the bottom of the page anyway. All in all the submenu element gets hidden a bit by either falling completely out of the pages view half way through the element, or it gets hidden by the section tags overflow state.

With that. In a case where this happens I am wanting to instead of have the element align to the bottom of the trigger element, have it align to the top instead so that way the menu in that case is above the trigger element and not below.

Problem is Im not sure how to compensate for that.

Here is the function I came up with to do what I need, now I just need some help in a sense catching when the menu element falls off the page so to speak, so I can adjust for it when it does.

```
function openSubOrgMenu(triggerID, elem)
{
    orgSubOpenID = triggerID;
    orgSubShowing = true;

    elemOffset = elem.offset(); //trigger element
    elemWidth = elem.width();
    elemHeight = elem.height();

    elemWrap = elem.siblings('.org_group_wrapper');//menu element
    elemWrapWidth = elemWrap.width();
    elemWrapHeight = elemWrap.height();

    moveTop = elemHeight + elemOffset.top + 4;
    moveLeft = elemOffset.left - (elemWrapWidth-elemWidth-15);


    elemWrap.show().offset({top:moveTop, left:moveLeft});
}
```

Well here is a JS Fiddle, not necessarily showing a working logic of what I want, but demonstrating the desired effect when its an element that at the bottom of the page/section:
http://jsfiddle.net/4zwEr/

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle to help with troubleshooting?

Comment: I can give it a shot? lol, its a canned template, that I am adding functionality and other stuff, so to recreate the overall problem might be a pain in the... but ill give it a shot anyway

Comment: Added a jsfiddle, not that I think its worth much.. but hopefully it atleast expresses what Im after as an end result